# Change admin password programmatically using PHP or MySQL

Tags: admin, password, automation

As part of a build/deployment script I will need to programmatically set the site admin password.

I have read [this](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2361/what-is-the-mysql-function-for-exp-members-password-column) question but the output from the accepted answer does not work. I see extra columnd `salt` and `crypt_key`. I'm guessing these are use in when generating the password.

Does anybody know the function used to generate password?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try this code by putting withing a EE template and run:

```
ee()->load->library('auth');
ee()->auth->update_password([MEMBER ID], '[NEW PASSWORD]');
```

For EE2.4:

```
$EE =& get_instance();
$EE->load->library('auth');
$EE->auth->update_password([MEMBER ID], '[NEW PASSWORD]');
```

I hope, it would work for you.

Comment: Will do, thanks. It only dawned on me afterwards to look at the PHP code, silly me. Thanks.

Comment: Note here: above will work for EE2.6.0+.

Comment: Can you please try the updated code. I hope, it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you find that you need to get at this at a lower level, you might take a look at the source code in [AJW Member Import](https://bitbucket.org/ajweaver/ajw_import_members). (I was just using this as a reference for a similar need...)

In the do_import() function in ajw_import_members_model.php (line 186), you'll see this simple conversion of a plain text password to the proper hash used by EE:

```
$data["password"] = do_hash( $data["password"] );
```

The do_hash() function is just one of the [CodeIgniter Security Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/security_helper.html) functions.

It looks like this is just a standard SHA1 hash--if so, you should be able to hash the password in any language script (e.g., if your build / deploy script is Javascript/Node or Ruby, etc.)