# new password is still not working

Tags: password

I changed password correctly according to the procedure but the new password still not working. I can not access control panel of my website to change some contents.
Please help

Comment: Could you confirm what is happening - when you log in, do you just get returned to the login prompt, or does it specifically state that you have entered the wrong password? Are there any other super admins that can reset the password for you?

Answer (score 0):

How did you change password? which steps did you folllow?

you can check this thread possible duplicate: [Change admin password programmatically using PHP or MySQL](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13389/change-admin-password-programmatically-using-php-or-mysql)