# How to reset password with email being setup

Tags: forgot-password

I'm using expression engine 2.0 and email is not set up. I need to reset the password but the application requires an email to be sent out.

Is there a way to reset the password without email? I'd like to just get the reset link/token and not try and encrypt and insert a password by hand. Any sug

Comment: Do you want to reset EE's Admin panel's password?

Comment: Yes. That would work swimmingly. Thought I have figured out a workaround to my problem I'm going to post it but please tell us.

Comment: You can also set your password directly on the database with a quick bit of SQL. `UPDATE exp_members
SET password = SHA1('pass123')
WHERE member_id = 1` See this answer for more detail: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/2365/22

Answer (score 1):

Request a reset code on the website. This will create a reset code and the next step will be to retrieve the reset code from the database.

Find your memeber_id searching for username or email in

```
SELECT *
FROM exp_members;
```

Find the reset code in the

```
SELECT member_id, resetcode
FROM exp_reset_password
WHERE member_id = <your_member_id>
```

Navigate to this link using the resetcode found in exp_reset_password table.

```
http://localhost/system/index.php?S=0&D=cp&C=login&M=reset_password&resetcode=<reset_code>
```